# How can I validate required fields?

Tags: users, forms

I don't care about having custom error message or anything, but I just want AN error message.  Right now on my registration form I have a variety of supplemental fields listed as required but that has no affect on a user's ability to submit the form.  How can I prevent them from submitting if the field is null?  I don't care about crazy condiitionals or anything, simply if its null to not let them submit.  I have been unsuccessfuly trying to code a validation module and I can't figure out the code.  I really just need something to work ASAP.  I have tried the validation module but it doesn't work for me - no clue why.

Maybe there is something wrong with my theme, does anybody know where that validation would normally be found so I could check?  it seems other people do get the error message.

Any help would be SUPER appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely something wrong with your theme, or a custom/contrib module you've got installed. Required fields are **always** validated and checked for empty values; they just piggy-back off the FAPI [`#required`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#required) property which I've never known not to work.

As far as debugging goes:

- Check the context the registration form is being displayed in. If you're manually adding the registration form in your theme, and doing so in a template file, the problem is simply that the messages produced by the form builder are being built after `$messages` has already been outputted in page.tpl.php (ignore this one if the problem is happening on the main registration page).
- Change the default theme back to Garland and see if the problem persists.
- If it does, start methodically disabling contributed and custom modules to isolate the culprit. Start with custom modules, then dev/alpha/beta contrib modules (in that order), then the stable modules. Check the registration form each time you disable one.
- To make sure there isn't some sort of conflict between your theme and a custom/contrib module, make sure you switch back to your custom theme before starting to disable modules.
- If all else fails, install a fresh copy of Drupal as a test site, add a couple of required fields to the user entity, and check the registration form again. If it works, you know there's something definitely wrong with your main installation. If it *doesn't* (which is extremely unlikely), you know the problem is more sinister (i.e. it's a crazy problem with PHP/MySQL/your OS)